# Mono - mod_mono consuming 100% of CPU

Tags: c#, apache, asp.net-mvc-3, mono, mod-mono

I'm running ASP.NET MVC 3 site on Mono 3.2.8 (Ubuntu 14.04 + Apache2.4.7 + mod_mono). I've noticed that there are two processes eating up all CPU. 
Running htop:

[image]

I also constantly get this entry in my log:

```
WARNING: WebConfigurationManager's LRUcache evictions count reached its max size
Cache Size: 100 (overridable via MONO_ASPNET_WEBCONFIG_CACHESIZE)
------------
[Fri Jun 05 06:49:53.446031 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21501] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
mod-mono-server received a shutdown message
mod-mono-server received a shutdown message
mod-mono-server received a shutdown message
mod-mono-server received a shutdown message
mod-mono-server received a shutdown message
```

Any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042411/mono-4-6-2-high-cpu-usage-on-server/48609403#48609403